Arguments in favor of constituent ontology?
What is the reason for thinking that there is such a thing as proper parts and that things like properties are parts of an object. Why believe that things are metaphysically composite, let alone physically composite considering how even that it is in dispute among philosophers (see mereological nihilism)? Further reading on this would be appreciate (especially from a Thomistic / Aristotelian point of view). Thanks!

Because ordinary and scientific discourses posit things as having parts. To displace the default, we need strong arguments against it and so far the arguments for nihilism are not too impressive. In practice, it amounts to linguistic exercises of replacing "tables" with "simples arranged tablewise", and it is unclear that this has any metaphysical import as opposed to being a pragmatic choice of phraseology. For critical discussions and references see SEP, 1 and 2.
